# How can I persist a sudo-session even when the calling user logs out?

Tags: sudo, archlinux, systemd

I have a longer running `sudo` (or `su`) command that needs to continue to run even if the user who initially invoked the command logs out.

Obviously `sudo sleep 60 & killall --user $USER` also kills the sleep-command, as it's a child of my tmux/zsh process:

```
# pstree -s `pidof sleep`
systemd───tmux───zsh───sudo───sleep
```

**How can I "lift" that command into the actual root process hierarchy - or make it persist the logout in any other way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nohup` or make another tmux window.

Comment: Thanks. `nohup` works. Using another tmux session would fail, as I run `killall --user ${USER}`. I updated the question accordingly.